# Getting a dynamic v-model to compare to data - VueJS and Vuelidate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I'm working on a simple form that shows 3 elements

1. A starting barcode field
2. An ending barcode field
3. A label field

A user enters 2 barcodes in each field. The first 2 digits of the barcodeEnd value gets compared against the allBarcodePrefixes data to see if there is a match, and prints the corresponding agency name or "Agency Not Found" if there is no match. If there is no match, the form stops there (user must fix the barcode entry) but if it finds a match it brings up a new line with a newly generated set of field and v-models

This was working fine until I made the v-models dynamic so I can manipulate each entry independently for validations and value

**PROBLEM**
Two odd things are happening I need help with guys.

1. The starting barcode field clears out when I blur out and into the next input field. Then when I enter something there, it comes back! I have a clear console too so I have no idea what is going on.
2. The `showAgencyName()` method is supposed to get the v-model and compare it to the data to get the agency name. But my v-model is dynamic and in a string literal. I'm not sure how to pull this value

I have the code in a [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/OJyxLPB?editors=1010) for you to check it out and see what I mean. I put the `onAddBarcodes` function in the failing line so you can see it validate correctly (that part works). Eventually, this line will be removed since it's only supposed to validate for minLength and maxLength after it validated for the agency first.

```
    <div id="q-app">
        <div class="q-pa-md">
          <div>
            <div v-for="(barcode, index) in barcodes" :key="index">
              <div class="full-width row no-wrap justify-start items-center q-pt-lg">
                <div class="col-3">
                  <label>Starting Roll #:</label>
                  <q-input outlined square dense v-model="$v[`barcodeStart${index}`].$model"></q-input>

                  <div class="error-msg">
                    <div v-if="!$v[`barcodeStart${index}`].maxLength || !$v[`barcodeStart${index}`].minLength">
                      <span> Must be exactly 9 characters. </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-3">
                  <label>Ending Roll #:</label>
                  <q-input outlined square dense v-model="$v[`barcodeEnd${index}`].$model" @change="showAgencyName(barcode)"></q-input>
                  <div class="error-msg">
                    <div v-if="!$v[`barcodeEnd${index}`].maxLength || !$v[`barcodeEnd${index}`].minLength">
                      <span> Must be exactly 9 characters. </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-3">
                  <label>Agency:</label>
                  <div v-if="barcode.agencyName">
                    {{ barcode.agencyName }}
                  </div>
                  <div v-else></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      Vue.use(window.vuelidate.default)
      const { required, minLength, maxLength } = window.validators

      new Vue({
        el: '#q-app',
        data () {
          return {
            barcodes: [
              {
                barcodeStart: "",
                barcodeEnd: "",
                agencyName: ""
              }
            ],
            newPackage: "",
            reset: true,
            allBarcodePrefixes: {
              "10": "Boston",
              "11": "New York",
              "13": "Houston",
              "14": "Connecticut",
              "16": "SIA",
              "17": "Colorado",
              "18": "Chicago"
            }
          }
        },
        validations() {
          const rules = {};
          this.barcodes.forEach((barcode, index) => {
            rules[`barcodeStart${index}`] = {
                minLength: minLength(9),
                maxLength: maxLength(9)
            };
          });

          this.barcodes.forEach((barcode, index) => {
            rules[`barcodeEnd${index}`] = {
                minLength: minLength(9),
                maxLength: maxLength(9)
            };
          });
          return rules;
        },
        methods: {
          onAddBarcodes() {
            // creating a new line when requested on blur of barcodeEnd
            const newBarcode = {
              barcodeStart: "",
              barcodeEnd: "",
              agencyName: ""
            };
            this.barcodes.push(newBarcode);
          },

          showAgencyName(barcode) {
            var str = barcode.barcodeEnd; // I need to pull the v-model value
            var res = str.substring(0, 2); //get first 2 char of v-model
            if (this.allBarcodePrefixes[res] == undefined) {
              //compare it to data
              barcode.agencyName = "Agency not found"; //pass this msg if not matched
              this.onAddBarcodes(); //adding it to the fail just for testing
            } else {
              barcode.agencyName = this.allBarcodePrefixes[res]; //pass this if matched
              this.onAddBarcodes(); //bring up a new line
            }
          },
        }
      })
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is set the v-model to the object in your v-for loop. So that it will look like this.

```
<q-input outlined square dense v-model="barcode.barcodeStart"></q-input>
```

and

```
<q-input outlined square dense v-model="barcode.barcodeEnd"></q-input>
```

This way they update the barcode object and due to it being an observable your `showAgencyName` function can stay as it is and the barcode object in it will be updated.

EDIT

When you call the onchange event you can then pass through the index

```
@change="showAgencyName(barcode, index)"
```

then in your showAgencyName function you can access the validation with `this.$v`.

To make sure the rules have past you will need to update the `$model`. Like this

```
 this.$v[`barcodeStart${index}`].$model = barcode.barcodeStart
this.$v[`barcodeEnd${index}`].$model = barcode.barcodeEnd

// Check for errors
if (this.$v[`barcodeEnd${index}`].$error) {
   return
}
```

Comment: Then I can't validate it and it won't be dynamic. That's the traditional way of doing it and the way I had it in the initial design. Since the fields are being generated dynamically they must have their unique dynamically generated v-model

Comment: You can continue to do the above then access the validation in your `showAgencyName` with `this.$v`. Then on change you can pass the index too `@change="showAgencyName(barcode, index)"` to then access the validation `this.$v[\`barcodeEnd${index}\`]`

Comment: I'll try this. WHy not making a proper answer so I can credit you?

Comment: Have you tested in the codepen I provided? It doesn't seem to work, unless I am putting the snippets in the wrong place

Comment: Cannot set property '$model' of undefined

Comment: Ah sorry, I added the dollar in the wrong place when editing my answer

Comment: The undefined $model  went away but $index is now there. If I pass it to the function, I get barcoeEnd and barcodeStart undefined instead. can you check my codepen here https://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/OJyxLPB?editors=1010

Comment: You can pass in both `barcode` and `index` then on this line `var str = this.$v.barcode.barcodeEnd;` you don't need to get the barcode from this.$v just use `var str = barcode.barcodeEnd`

Comment: Awesome! It works perfectly now! Hopefully any future visitors can understand all this back and forth lol. Thanks a lot bud!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I managed to help :) when it comes to the validation I think one of the issues is the dynamic validation rules which vuelidate seems to have trouble with. I find [v-validate](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/) to be very helpful and might could be a good alternative